# LeafletJS : Trigger Popup at Zoom End to Show Details of Clicked Feature

Tags: javascript, events, popup, leaflet

I'm currently using popup like this when clicking a feature. Basically it zooms and show a popup with feature details :

```
    function ClickPopup(e) {    
        var layer = e.target;
        name = e.target.feature.properties.name;
        var main_popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng(e.latlng())
        .setContent('<span class="big-text">'+name+'</span>')
        .openOn(map);
    }  

  function zoomToFeature(e) {
      map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
      ClickPopup(e);
  } 

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature,
        });  
   }
```

It works more or less because popup is coming too quickly (ie before end of zoom) so popup is somtimes badly placed.
So I'd like to get the popup at the end of zoom by using "zoomend" event :

```
map.on('zoomend',function(e){ console.log("Zoom End"); });
```

My problem is that I'm unable to get/retrieve/pass the layer and feature clicked from/to this map event (e.target.feature) to display his details.

Does anyone know how to worakaround this ?
Thanks,
T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass context/scope to leaflet events. Here's with without passing context:

```
function onMapMoveEnd () {
    console.log(this); // this === map
}

function onLayerClick () {
    console.log(this); // this === layer
    map.once('moveend', onMapMoveEnd);
    map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', onLayerClick);
}
```

Now with passing layer context to the map's moveend event handler:

```
function onMapMoveEnd () {
    console.log(this); // this === layer
}

function onLayerClick () {
    console.log(this); // this === layer
    map.once('moveend', onMapMoveEnd, this); // passing context
    map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
}
```

So now you can just use `this` in the moveend handler because it references the layer. Here's a complete example:

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
    layers: [
        new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ]
});

var feature = {
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {
        property: 'value'
    },
    geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: [[[-30, 30], [30, 30], [30, -30], [-30, -30]]]
    }
};

function onMapMoveEnd () {
    this.bindPopup(this.feature.properties.property).openPopup();
}

function onLayerClick () {
    map.once('moveend', onMapMoveEnd, this);
    map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', onLayerClick);
}

new L.GeoJSON(feature, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 1.0.3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanations and full example. Tested and it works great. Thanks again !

Comment: No need to thank, always welcome. That's what we are here for. You could accept the answer so others with the same problem can find an accepted answer too :)